# Running do while loop results in fatal error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to use the google drive api to get list of files in a particular folder. Now when I try to run a do..while loop in order to fetch file list in small chunks, the app crashes with a fatal error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**Snippet**

```
function listFiles(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    let pageToken = null;

    do {
        drive.files.list({
            pageSize: 10,
            q: "'root' in parents and trashed=false",
            fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
            pageToken: pageToken,
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.error(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);

            pageToken = res.data.nextPageToken;
            const files = res.data.files;

            if (files.length) {
                files.forEach((file) => {
                    console.log(`${file.name}  (${file.id})`);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("No files found!");
            }
        });
    }
    while(!pageToken);
```

**AFAIK** nextPageToken will be undefined if there are no more files.

Comment: Nope. I tried it and it doesnt work. Same issue. Also my pc resources gets hogged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you’ve heard of the term "async" in JS. Apparently `drive.files.list` is a callback style async function. And this `pageToken = res.data.nextPageToken` assignment happens inside that callback, which means pageToken’s value doesn’t change instantly from `null` to `something`

However your do...while logic happens synchronously. Thus `while(!pageToken)` basically equals `while(true)`. That’s why you got the error, your program stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: Yes I do have heard the term. So basically what you are suggesting is to rewrite into async/await style?